# Google maps API: App keeps crashing when I try to use the map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

So I am currently trying to develop an app that needs a google map API. Whenever I try to load the map, the app I implemented my map as a subclass of the fragment class:

```
package io.github.danisharsalan.meetupmarker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapActivityFragment extends Fragment {

MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_activity, container, false);

    mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume(); //needed to make map display immediately

    try{
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;

            // For showing a move to my location button
            //googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"));

            // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory(){
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}


}'
```

and here is the xml file, titled fragment_map_activity.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="io.github.danisharsalan.meetupmarker.MapActivityFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The logcat gives me this problem:

> 02-25 00:29:10.924 5473-5473/io.github.danisharsalan.meetupmarker
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: io.github.danisharsalan.meetupmarker, PID: 5473
> java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml
> at
> com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.q.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11947480:40)
> at
> com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11947480:11)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11947480:112)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11947480:30)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.h.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11947480:45)
> at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeu.zza(Unknown Source)
> at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
> at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
> at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
> at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
> at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
> at
> io.github.danisharsalan.meetupmarker.MapActivityFragment.onCreateView(MapActivityFragment.java:33)
> at
> android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
> at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
> at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
> at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
> at
> android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
> at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
> at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
> at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
> at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
> at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

How do I fix my API key problem? Thank you.

**EDIT:** It turns out that I was simply missing my API key where It was supposed to be referenced. My apologies for creating a low-quality question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Google Maps API key wasn't added to the AndroidManifest file. 
You can grab Google Maps API key from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)

Insert the API key as follows just before the closing tag `</application >`

```
 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```